# Any alternative way of using loadall() method in hibernate 4 without using hibernate template

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on hibernate 4 and don't want to use the hibernate template which is extended from hibernate dao support for calling the loadAll() method is there any way how can we call loadAll() without calling hibernatetemplate in hibernate 4 version?

Comment: You can perform a simple select all query